# Where can I find the little snap-on fixtures that hold my Yaris bumper in place?

Tags: parts, yaris, bumper

I hit a pot-hole the other day, and the bumper on my Yaris lost some of it's snap-on fixtures. I checked with Advanced Auto Parts, and they rudely informed me that they can't possibly stock every little part for every different car. Where should I look?

Comment: Do you have a picture?  Amazon and other online sources absolutely stock fittings that are likely the same as what you're looking for.

Comment: I'll take one and post it in a little bit. They have a center portion that collapses if you push it with a pen.

Comment: Online as @BobCross said, or more likely you'll find them at the dealership. They will put a picture up on the screen and you can help them drill in to find your part.

Comment: Then, yes, as soon as you post a picture, we will be able to think of a provider. I bought a bunch of bits like that from Amazon a couple of months ago. Pro tip: buy them in biggest bag available.

Answer (score 1):

Ebay is the best place to look for these little parts try different combination of names,try Amazon look up google shopping,if it is an old car, places like AAA salvage yard, u pull r parts and some used parts stores in the city, dealership is last, they charge a lot even for a screw.

Comment: He's right, the dealership will have these, but they tend to be overpriced for bits of plastic they are. eBay and some auto parts stores have various types that you can try to match.

Comment: I'd personally call the dealership to get a price.  You may be pleasantly surprised.  We're working on a Toyota Celica GT-Four at the moment and have been quite shocked by how little the dealership is charging from spares.  In many cases they're cheaper than ebay.  Worth at least a phone call.